# Weird Opacity animation behavior after adding Composition Light effect

Tags: uwp, windows-composition-api, xaml-composition

So I'm currently using Windows composition Apis to create a "fade-in" animation, combining a scale animation and an opacity animation, to my custom control, which worked perfectly fine. However, recently I tried to add some light effect but for some reason the opacity animation doesn't work out anymore.

Here is how it looks
[image]

As you can see, you are able to see the image during the "fade-in" animation without light effect. But once you add the light effect, you are not able to see it until the "fade-in" animation is done. It must be some mechanics of composition animation but I just used them in a wrong way.

You can reproduce the code here

MainPage.xaml(Use your own image):

```
<Grid x:Name="rootPanel" Background="LightGray" Loaded="rootPanel_Loaded">
<Image x:Name="panel" Source="Assets/aaa.jpg" Loaded="panel_Loaded" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
private Compositor _compositor;
private const float lightDepth = 300f;
private const int animationDelay = 600;
private const int animationDuration = 70;
private CompositionEffectFactory _effectFactory;
private Random _random = new Random();
private PointLight _pointLight;
private Visual _root;
private ImplicitAnimationCollection _implicitAnimations1st;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;


    _implicitAnimations1st = _compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();
    var _firstWaveAnimationGroup = _compositor.CreateAnimationGroup();

    var OpacityAnimation1st = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    OpacityAnimationSetting(OpacityAnimation1st, (double)0);

    var scaleAnimation1st = _compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
    ScaleAnimationSetting(scaleAnimation1st, (double)0);

    _firstWaveAnimationGroup.Add(OpacityAnimation1st);
    _firstWaveAnimationGroup.Add(scaleAnimation1st);
    _implicitAnimations1st["Offset"] = _firstWaveAnimationGroup;
}

private void ScaleAnimationSetting(Vector3KeyFrameAnimation animation, double delay)
{
    animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, new Vector3(0.7f, 0.7f, -.5f));
    animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, new Vector3(1, 1, 0), _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800);
    animation.DelayTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay);
    animation.DelayBehavior = AnimationDelayBehavior.SetInitialValueAfterDelay;
    animation.Target = "Scale";
}

private void OpacityAnimationSetting(ScalarKeyFrameAnimation animation, double delay)
{
    animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 1.0f, _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800);
    animation.DelayTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay);
    animation.DelayBehavior = AnimationDelayBehavior.SetInitialValueAfterDelay;
    animation.Target = "Opacity";
}

private void panel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(panel);
    visual.Opacity = 0f;
    visual.ImplicitAnimations = _implicitAnimations1st;
    visual.CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(panel.DesiredSize.Width / 2), (float)(panel.DesiredSize.Height / 2), 0);
    visual.Offset = new Vector3((float)-panel.DesiredSize.Width, (float)-panel.DesiredSize.Height, 0);
}

private void rootPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _root = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(rootPanel);
    _pointLight = _compositor.CreatePointLight();
    _pointLight.Offset = new Vector3(-2500f, -2500f, 300f);
    _pointLight.Intensity = 1.3f;
    IGraphicsEffect graphicsEffect = new CompositeEffect()
    {
        Mode = CanvasComposite.DestinationIn,
        Sources =
                    {
                        new CompositeEffect()
                        {
                            Mode = CanvasComposite.Add,
                            Sources =
                            {
                                new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("ImageSource"),
                                new SceneLightingEffect()
                                {
                                    AmbientAmount = 0,
                                    DiffuseAmount = .5f,
                                    SpecularAmount = 0,
                                    NormalMapSource = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("NormalMap"),
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("NormalMap"),
                    }
    };

    _effectFactory = _compositor.CreateEffectFactory(graphicsEffect);

    //Comment Out the rest of the two lines can remove light effect
    _pointLight.CoordinateSpace = _root;
    _pointLight.Targets.Add(_root);

    #region First light animation
    Vector3KeyFrameAnimation lightPositionAnimation;
    lightPositionAnimation = _compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
    lightPositionAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(.0f, new Vector3(200f, 700f, lightDepth), _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
    lightPositionAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, new Vector3(200f, 700f, lightDepth), _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
    lightPositionAnimation.DelayTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(animationDelay);
    lightPositionAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animationDuration);
    lightPositionAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

    _pointLight.StartAnimation("Offset", lightPositionAnimation);
    #endregion

}
}
```

How do I be able to fix it?

Comment: I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. Currently, there is a workaround that you could refer. you could use [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations`](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) to Integrate `Opacity` and `Scale` animation:  `panel.Scale(duration: 2000, scaleX: (float)1.1, scaleY: (float)1.1).Fade(1f, duration: 2000).Start();` And use `Light` method to process light animation individually.  `rootPanel.Light(distance: 500, duration: 2000, delay: 0).Start();`

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT I tried the workaround but unfortunately it does not reach my need. Im not only require light effect on the page but also I need it moving around the page as well as changing the color. Unfortunately I don't see such provided. I tried using scale and fade animation from toolkit and manual composition animation but the problem still exists. I doubt it might be a bug but I'm still put conservative opinion on this until some pros confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting some days after posting problem as issue on the github repo of Windows UI, one of the Windows UI developers gave a solution to fix such question.

A quote from this developer:

> Items not currently targeted by or being illuminated by the point light when animating will appear black. To illuminate surrounding visuals not targeted by the light in a natural way, use an ambient light in conjunction with other lights.
>
> _ambientLight = _compositor.CreateAmbientLight();
>
> _ambientLight.Targets.Add(_root);

After adding such code in my project, it really fix the problem.